# Why should I allow multiple IP addresses on a website for a single session?

Tags: security

I hope my question matches the scope of this site.

I'm developing a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). Currently my logged in users are locked to their IP address for the session. Unfortunately a small portion of my userbase constantly jump between two or more IP addresses. Most of them probably use load balancers. Technically it is not necessary to lock the users sessions to one IP address. I did not expect clients to switch between multiple IP addresses for a single page request on my website.

I wonder now, what are the risks in allowing my clients to constantly jump between IP addresses for a page request (for example, CSS files are requested by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and JavaScript files are requested by yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy)? Should I generally allow or prohibit that?

Comment: You don't even need load balancers to jump around IPs. Connect on your phone on the subway, you might get a different IP every few minutes as the train travels, and then again when your phone switches to WiFi at a destination.

Comment: Also for laptops moving between locations (say, home > work > starbucks). Also: IPv6 random addresses (IPv6 SLAAC privacy extensions).

Comment: intuitively, I would expect the client jumping around on different source Ips to cause problems if it was anything more than "occasionally".

Comment: **If**  you are developing a webapp that will be installed in a network that you control or you have knowledge of you *may* decide to do this for security since you might be able to say "in this situation multiple IPs are not going to happen since users must access this from their WS and there are no load balancers or other stuff in between that may change their IP"... in that case you might even be able to track the users IPs since their WS may always have the same one (or it might change only once every couple of months)

Comment: @TomH No, the vast majority of webapps don't care about your IP address, they will accept the same cookies in an HTTP request over a new TCP connection. Only demented and badly designed crap locks your session to an IP or a connection.

Comment: And one more reason why ip-addresses can change: The user could be using a browser with cookie-synchronization over multiple devices. Then multiple devices will use the same session in parallel or after each other. He might be having some tabs open on his laptop and also tap on a link in a mail he receives on his phone. - or the laptop might just still be running and refreshing the page, while the user is away and using his tablet.

Answer (score 36):

> a small portion of my userbase constantly jump between two or more IP addresses.

## Causes

Assuming that your users aren't actively trying to hide their real IP addresses by using an anonymising service...:

Most corporate examples I have seen are caused by larger companies and some ISP's using a cluster of proxy servers, each with a different external IP-address, with user requests getting load balanced over that cluster.

You may see Dual Stack users making requests over both IPv4 and IPv6  and switching between the two protocols [RFC 8305](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305) for subsequent requests.

The other scenario is when I'm at the extreme range of a Wi-Fi access point and my device "randomly" switches between Wi-Fi and cellular data.

## Solutions

In the first scenario you might compromise on keeping such IP address "security" in your sessions by only considering the first three octets, as typically such a cluster of proxy servers are all within a small subnet and will have neighboring IP addresses.

In the second and third scenario you will see completely different client IP addresses, from unrelated providers even.

Don't tie you sessions to a specific IP address, that is more likely to break user experience than to provide actual improved security.

Comment: Nobody ties sessions to IP addresses anymore, for exactly these reasons.

Comment: NEVER ever tie sessions to IP-addresses, the 80s are over! My ISP supplys a complete /64 network to my *phone* in which my browser jumps around like crazy.

Comment: In addition to all, Multipath TCP is getting increasingly common.

Comment: If you are making your CMS for technical users, you can put a "limit this session to your ip (xxx.yyy.zzz.iii) only" checkbox on the login page

Comment: @bjoster that's because the IPv6 privacy extensions, it keep switching address so websites cannot track you by your ip alone (this is not an issue with IPv4, as multiple people are behind the same address)

Comment: Can your IP also not change randomly while you're on a cellular data? Certainly if you're traveling abroad and roaming, and your phone switches from one network to another.

Comment: @Ferrybig: Possibly also because the data connection is frequently torn down (for power saving) and reestablished. Privacy-extensions addresses normally last ~10 hours if the connection is stable.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - If only it were so! About a year ago, I discovered that the open source library system Koha still locks sessions to IP address by default. (...and about 5 minutes later, I told our Koha admins to turn the IP lock off.)

Comment: @DaveSherohman Yeah, but it's also been around a very long time, and locking sessions to IP addresses used to be common practice.

Comment: @Vilx IIRC (so this is probably wrong) when you are roaming all your traffic is tunneled back to your home network, and out to the Internet from there. That's why it's often more expensive.

Comment: @immibis - Perhaps. To be honest, I don't know either. I just though it would make more sense that you use the local resources instead of tunneling back. The high fees would be because the operators would probably charge each other at elevated rates for using their infrastructure (they are competitors after all).

Answer (score 9):

> I wonder now, what are the risks in allowing my clients to constantly jump between IP addresses for a page request (for example, CSS files are requested by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and JavaScript files are requested by yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy)? Should I generally allow or prohibit that?

The primary risk is a malicious user hijacking the session.  If you could lock down to one or a small set of IP addresses, you could block users from entirely different IP addresses from hijacking the session.

The problem is that some users do this legitimately.  Whether they are using a load balanced proxy or are at the margins of two wireless access points (or whatever), they use multiple IP addresses.  So you pretty much have to allow it for those users.  And it's hard to tell which users require multiple IP addresses except when they request from multiple IP addresses.

One way to reduce the impact of this is to use HTTPS.  Then the malicious actor has to have a way to compromise the secure layer as well as the session cookie.  Over an insecure connection, the malicious actor could just use network inspection to compromise a session cookie.  But over HTTPS, the same malicious actor needs to have access to one of the ends of the conversation.  And if the malicious actor has that, then it's not necessary to use a different IP.

**TL;DR**:  you should generally allow requests from different IP addresses for the same user.  There are legitimate reasons this can happen.  Use HTTPS instead to protect from that class of exploits.

Answer (score 4):

> what are the risks in allowing my clients to constantly jump between IP addresses for a page request

From a security standpoint - zero risks.

Now, from a practical standpoint. It means you cannot use certain types of algorithms for either security or [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) protection.

A simple way to throttle user requests is to track by IP address. Since this doesn't need to interact with your application server you can use services at lower levels to do this. Software like Apache's mod_evasive do this. You can still use these techniques, but user changing IP addresses will reduce their effectiveness. Then again, users will switch IP addresses anyway so these techniques have never really been effective.

A related, but different, use-case is throttling failed login attempts. This is to prevent brute-force password guessing. But again, there is nothing you can do anyway if users change IP addresses. A really serious hacker would not even use his own machines. He'd just buy some time on a botnet (or use his own previously infected botnet) and connect to your service via 10,000 other people's PCs (IP addresses). This is not really related to limiting user's IP address because it is pre-login, but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There a several reasons why a user may jump to a new IP address.

1. IPv6 privacy extensions, many IPv6 clients nowadays will jump around within the /64 on the lan.
2. Load balanced proxies, the clients request gets routed to one of several proxies each with a seperate IP.
3. NAT pools, the border nat is configured with multiple IP addresses and assigns IP/port combinations from the pool arbitarilly to client TCP connections.
4. The user moves between different networks or parts of a network, common with phones nowadays.
5. Dual stack users may hop between IPv4 and IPv6.

> I wonder now, what are the risks in allowing my clients to constantly jump between IPs for a page request

The advantage of locking client sessoins to IPs is it makes session stealing attacks harder. If an attacker has a mechanism that lets them steal the clients cookies but does not let them make connections to your server from the clients IP address then the IP lock will block them from stealing the session.

The downside is as you say it will cause breakage for some users who find their session invalidated for no obvious reason.

Most sites nowadays seem to think the breakage outweighs the benefits of such locking.